# Prepared statements used incorrectly in ACF?

Tags: advanced-custom-fields, warnings, wpdb

I've just updated to WP 3.9 and it returns a warning when using placeholders incorrectly. I've found some prepared statements written incorrectly, but I really got worried when I saw this in the ACF-plugin (because it's so widely used): (Take a look at the export.php in the core files of the plugin)

```
// create SQL with %d placeholders
$where = 'WHERE ID IN (' . substr(str_repeat('%d,', count($my_options['acf_posts'])), 0, -1) . ')';

// now prepare the SQL based on the %d + $_POST data
$posts = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->posts} $where", $my_options['acf_posts']));
```

This seems to be a vulneribility in the plugin? (because the abscence of actual placeholders in the actual prepare-statement (they're using `$where` instead ) or am I totally incorrect in my assumtpion? Please guide me :-)

Comment: I would definitely raise this with the plugin author, as this is more a question related to the plugin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that you ARE incorrect.

Let's taka a closer look at this code you mentioned in your question.

In first line it sets `$where` variable:

```
$where = 'WHERE ID IN (' . substr(str_repeat('%d,', count($my_options['acf_posts'])), 0, -1) . ')';
```

So what this line really does is:

- get the number of some options (let's call it 'N')
- repeats `%d` placeholder N times
- append it to string `WHERE ID IN ('.`

So `$where` variable contains a string like this:

```
WHERE ID IN (%d, %d, %d, ...)
```

... and as you can see, this string CONTAINS placeholders.

Just after this line comes real query, which is build using this `$where` variable, and the option values ARE inserted using these placeholders.

There isn't anything bad in using variables, when you build query string, if these variables contains safe strings (i. e. don't contain values comming from user).

---

PS. Take a look at this code:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->posts} WHERE ID=%d";
$results = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare( $sql, 10 ) );
```

Do you think this is also a vulneribility?

Comment: Ok. Thank you!!! I really didn't thought it was bad code in the plugin (else someone else had probably seen that a long, long time ago) I was just curious. And of course, you're totally right! (I was "stuck" thinking it's not ok to have variables in the prepare-function)

Comment: No problem. Sometimes it's good to doubt :)

Comment: Please remind me to award your bounty. I can't do it beore 10 hours has gone...

Comment: You should be able to do it now.